# Unable to set unique_ptr<Basic> to p(new Basic())

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, unique-ptr

I have a `Basic` class that is pretty generic. (As shown below) I'm attempting to store the pointer in a `unique_ptr<Basic>` to store in a vector,  `vector<unique_ptr<Basic>>`

```
class Basic:
public BaseClass
{
public:
    Basic();
    ~Basic();
};
```

There is another [host] class that contains this vector, and houses this member:

```
void BasicManagement::CreateBasicEntry(){
    unique_ptr<Basic> e_Basic = p( new Basic() );
    LocalBasicQueue.push_back(e_Basic);
}
```

Where `LocalBasicQueue` is a `vector<unique_ptr<Basic>>`. Maybe my initialization is wrong, but I'm getting intellisense errors, and I can't seem to assign a pointer to a new class instance to store in the vector.

(Compiler error for "p" )`11    IntelliSense: call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or conversion functions to pointer-to-function type  c:\Us...agement.cpp 15  32  TestManagement`

Comment: Typo: `Base` vs `Basic` ?

Comment: Sorry about that - Just fixed it. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unique_ptr`'s constructor is explicit. You should construct `e_Base` like this:

```
unique_ptr<Basic> e_base{new Basic};
```

Also, note that you can't just `push_back` a `unique_ptr`, since it's not copyable. You'd need to `std::move()` it.

Comment: Thanks! This option worked! Would the new syntax be `LocalBasicQueue.push_back(std::move(e_base);`?

Comment: Also, gotta love the fact that seasoned coders skip over all of the typo's, surfing the context. xD I wish my compiler would do that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't write `new Basic()`, use `new Basic` instead.